# Convert DateTime axis data back to DateTime

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, oxyplot

I've got a LineSeries where DataFieldX values are DateTime, visually its working great but after implementing OnClick for the chart I can't seem to convert the selected value back to DateTime:

```
        Plot plot = sender as Plot;
        var series = plot.GetSeriesFromPoint(new ScreenPoint(e.GetPosition(plot).X, e.GetPosition(plot).Y), 10);
        var result = series.GetNearestPoint(new ScreenPoint(e.GetPosition(plot).X, e.GetPosition(plot).Y), true);
        var data = result.DataPoint;
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = dt.AddSeconds(data.X);
```

data.X is 41577.61596880656, and the time for the point in the chart is 31/10/2013 14:47. dt ends up being 01.01.0001 11:32:57

How can I successfully convert data.X back to DateTime?

Comment: Never used oxyplot, but maybe this will help: http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/348859

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add days, not seconds to the date December 31, 1899

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1899,12,31);
dt = dt.AddDays(data.X);
```

For some reason when I run this I'm off by 0.3 seconds.  I'm assuming that is based off of the precision of the format the data is being stored in.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't `DateTimeAxis.ToDateTime()` perform the required conversion?